# Question about proof that every bounded subset of the integers has a largest element

Tags: solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum, integers

Supposing we have a nonempty subset $A_0$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ bounded from above, I'm trying to prove that $A_0$ has a largest element.

I've seen a few complicated proofs that are nothing like mine, and I'm a little concerned about a particular step of my proof, so I'd like to check if my argument is valid.

Proof:

Since $A_0$ is bounded from above and $A_0\subset\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{R}$, we have that $s:=\sup(A_0)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$ and is such that $s\geq a$ for all $a\in A_0$.

If $s\in A_0$, we are done since then $s$ is larger than all the elements of $A_0$, yet is a member of $A_0$ itself, so $s$ is the largest element of $A_0$.

If $s\notin A_0$, then still by definition $s>a$ for all $a\in A_0$, but not equal to any elements $a$ of $A_0$ since $s$ is not in $A_0$. Thus $\exists t=(s+a)/2$ such that $s>t>a$ for all $a\in A_0$, so $t$ is an upper bound of $A_0$ less than $s$, contradicting that $s$ is the *least* upper bound of $A_0$. So $s\in A_0$ after all. $\blacksquare$

I guess I'm concerned with the last paragraph and the naive construction of $t$ *for all* $a$. Any check would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are allowed to use in your proof.  If you are allowed to use the fact that $\mathbb N$ is well-ordered, then the argument is simple.  First, replace your set $A_0$ by $-A_0$ so as to have a subset of $\mathbb Z$ bounded from *below* rather than above.  Then use a lower bound $L$ to convert the set to one contained in $\mathbb N$, by adding $L$ (or $L+1$ depending on your definition of $\mathbb N$).  Now your set is contained in $\mathbb N$, and you can apply the well-order of $\mathbb N$ to conclude.

Comment: That is a nice proof. But I am allowed to use completeness and what not.

Comment: Do you mean completeness of $\mathbb R$?  Then use this completeness to prove the well-ordering property of $\mathbb N$, and then reduce your problem to that.  This is possibly the most conceptual approach.

Comment: We also then need to prove translations of sets preserve smallest elements.

Comment: The more I think about this, I think a simple approach using your method would be to say: if $A_0$ is bounded above, say by $b$, then $b\geq a$ for all $a\in A_0$ so $b-a+1\geq 1$ for all $a\in A_0$ hence the set $A_1=\{b-a+1:a\in A_0\}$ is a subset of the positive integers, so we can invoke well ordering on $A_1$ to get a least element $s$ so that $s\leq b-a+1$ for all $a$ and $s=b-a_0+1$ for some $a_0\in A_0$. Thus $b-a_0+1\leq b-a+1$ so there exists $a_0$ in $A_0$ such that $a_0\geq a$ for all $a\in A_0$.

Answer (score 1):

When you define $t \in \mathbb{R}$ as the arithmetic mean between $s = \sup A_0$ and $a \in A_0,$ you're choosing a *particular* element of $A_0$ to do this, which doesn't necessarily imply that $t$ is an upper bound for $A_0.$ For $t$ to be an upper bound for $A_0$ you would need to pick the largest $a \in A_0,$ which defeats the purpose of your proof.

To arrive at a contradiction, I think you could argue as follows. First of all, note that $s$ has to be an integer, otherwise $\lfloor s \rfloor$ would be an upper bound for $A_0$ (there are no integers strictly between $\lfloor s \rfloor$ and $s$ if $s \notin \mathbb{Z}$), which contradicts the definition of $s.$ 
Now, if $s \notin A_0$, the number $s-1$ has to be in $A_0,$ otherwise it would be an upper bound and this again contradicts the definition of $s.$ But if $s-1 \in A_0$ then $s = \sup A_0 = s-1,$ which is impossible.

Comment: This line of argument works, but at the end you say "if $s-1 \in A_0$ then $s = \sup A_0 = s-1$..." and I think this requires a bit more justification.